# When building a custom view, the tag autocomplete widget position looks wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, custom-questions-list, tag-autocomplete

I was creating a custom view and noticed that the tag autocomplete widget appears at an awkward place:

[image]

*I'm using Chrome 72 on OSX*

Comment: Reproducible on Firefox Nightly 67.0a1. Wasn’t it working fine just a week ago?

Comment: Same issue on Safari 12 on OSX

Comment: Same issue on windows chrome 71